# TransportException Error when run composer install

Tags: laravel, composer-php

```
$ composer install
```

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

> Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error Retrying with
>   degraded mode, check
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode
>   for more info

Your configuration does not allow connection to http://packagist.org. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   Your configuration does not allow connection to http://packagist.org. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `composer.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this before `composer install`

```
composer clear-cache
```